# How to change dark theme with angular material?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, themes

I follow the documentation of angular material to make theme.

I have this:

[image]  [image]

And even if it seems to works fine, you can see that some items didn't change: background, icons...

In my `themes.scss` (which is well imported), I have this:

```
$themes-map: (
  indigo-pink: (
    primary-base: $mat-indigo,
    accent-base: $mat-pink,
  ),
  deeppurple-amber: (
    primary-base: $mat-deep-purple,
    accent-base: $mat-amber,
  ),
  pink-bluegrey: (
    primary-base: $mat-pink,
    accent-base: $mat-blue-gray,
  ),
  purple-green: (
    primary-base: $mat-purple,
    accent-base: $mat-green,
  )
);
```

I tried to add a dark theme, for example `deeppurple-amber-dark`:

```
deeppurple-amber-dark: (
  primary-base: $mat-deep-purple,
  accent-base: $mat-amber,
),
```

But the background of the menu to change theme always stay white, so I think I replace the basic theme. I tried to remove the `deeppurple-amber` theme to get the default one, but now I don't have anything on the theme selector...

I found that I should add `class="mat-app-background"`, so I have this:

```html
<body class="mat-app-background mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

But nothing change.

I'm not using the `mat-sidenav-container` such as other question refer. I'm using `mat-toolbar` but only for the header, so I don't know if it change something.

**How can I make all of those be compatible with dark theme ?**

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/github/mirismaili/AngularMaterialDynamicThemes) you can find an example of working project, without outdated versions.

You can check on [stackblitz](https://angular-ivy-tam66y.stackblitz.io). **Warn**: this can't work because stackblitz don't import repo from files.

Comment: Can you put up a demo of your code on stackblitz? 
I would suggest you try and simplify matters a bit ... mayube jut try to toggle between 2 themes, just send one parameter to "setActiveThem" dark: bool and try setting the theme.

Comment: @BobanStojanovski such as explain at the end, I tried but it doesn't import versions. I made a repository for the demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as i see it in your code is that you are not using Material as expected, you need to use the layout components it offers and the styles will be applied.

For example if i wrap the router outlet with mat-card like so:

```
<div class="content" role="main">
    <mat-card> 
         <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

[image]

I think Material is not a good option if you just want to use the styles without using the components, maybe try some CSS frameworks like bootstrap or tailwind.

Comment: Ok, but it's not possible to easily use bootstrap & material ? Material seems fine with multiple colors, but bootstrap is so much good with it card. Do you know how to make good card with material, or lot of theme with bootstrap ?

Comment: I would choose and stick with one. Bootstrap is simpler imho.
If you plan to use material ... you need not create a card component you already have that.

check here for card examples: https://material.angular.io/components/card/examples


All the components Material offers: https://material.angular.io/components/categories

Comment: Oh yes thanks ! I will do ti angular material's components :) Just, final things: the card are well changing of color but not the background, am I missing something ? The `role="main"` isn't enough ?