# Can't add found item for search bar

Tags: html, angular, searchbar

Actually, I have this:

[image]

I want to make a search bar like that:

[image]

Specially add all founded things below the search bar.

I'm using angular material and color theme such as explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71225995/how-to-change-dark-theme-with-angular-material).

After compiling, then edit, this is the code of the second picture (with green div) :

```html
<div style="display: contents;">
   <div style="display: contents;">
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="mat-form-field ng-tns-c111-0 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-input mat-form-field-appearance-fill mat-form-field-can-float ng-star-inserted" style="width: 33%; min-width: 50px; padding: 0;max-width: 500px;bottom: 0;" ng-reflect-appearance="fill">
         <div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c111-0" style="bottom: 0;">
            <div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c111-0">
               <div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c111-0">
                  <input matinput="" type="text" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c111-0 cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored" style="width: 33%; min-width: 50px; max-width: 500px;" ng-reflect-type="text" ng-reflect-placeholder="Search" placeholder="Search" id="mat-input-0" data-placeholder="Search" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false">
                  <span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c111-0">
                  </span>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mat-form-field-underline ng-tns-c111-0 ng-star-inserted" style="padding: 0;margin: 0;visibility: hidden;"><span class="mat-form-field-ripple ng-tns-c111-0"></span></div>
            <div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c111-0" ng-reflect-ng-switch="hint">
               <div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c111-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);">
                  <div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c111-0"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div style="background-color: green;">text</div>
      </mat-form-field>
   </div>
</div>
```

The HTML part that is compiled is this:

```html
<div style="display: contents;">
  <div style="display: contents;">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 33%; min-width: 50px; max-width: 500px;">
      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Search" style="width: 33%; min-width: 50px; max-width: 500px;">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to add the "test" div with my actual HTML code. I tried to add a div below the form field, or in the form field, like that:

```html
<div style="display: contents;">
  <div style="display: contents;">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 33%; min-width: 50px; max-width: 500px;">
      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Search" style="width: 33%; min-width: 50px; max-width: 500px;">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div id="search-field"></div>
</div>
```

Then, in typescript use:

```js
let div = document.getElementById("search-field");
let next = document.createElement("div");
next.innerHTML = "text";
next.classList.add("search-result");
div.appendChild(next);
```

But the div is added on the right of search bar (instead of below) :

[image]

Also, with different value than `display: contents`, I get things like that:

[image]

How can I make a good search bar?

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bvy7ug?file=src/app/app.module.ts) is a stackblitz that is not very well ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could not work by adding div into the angular material components. This is how I fix it :

1. Create own component for the result. For this answer, it will be named `<app-search-result>`.
2. Below the head bar, add a new div:

```html
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: 100;" id="search-result">
  <app-search-result *ngFor="let searchedItem of allSearchedItem" [item]="searchedItem"> </app-search-result>
</div>
```

The `position: fixed` allow it to move everywhere without moving other div. The `x-index` is only to make it showed hover other divs.

3. Move the search result div :

```js
@HostListener('window:resize')
onResize() {
  this.moveSearchResult();
}

moveSearchResult() {
  let searchResult = document.getElementById("search-result");
  if(searchResult == null)
    return;
  let fieldBox = document.getElementById("search-field").getBoundingClientRect();
  searchResult.style.marginLeft = fieldBox.x + "px";
}
```

The `search-field` is the id of the `mat-form-field`.

4. Just after adding content to the `allSearchedItem` array (that will contains all result), call `moveSearchResult()` method.

Now, this is what I have :

[image]

**Bonus**: I personnally add the same width/max-width as the input to make it as same size. Also, be careful with class that are declared into a specific component.